# Python virtualenv install scipy

Tags: python, linux, scipy, virtualenv

I'm trying to install *scipy* with *pip* on a machine I have limited access to, I can't run any *sudo* or *apt-get* commands. I made a python virtual enviroment and installed numpy in it, so far so good. But when I try to install *scipy*, I get "no lapack/blas resources found".

I tried to run

```
$ export LAPACK=/usr/lib/liblapack.so.3
$ export BLAS=/usr/lib/libblas.so
```

And then install scipy, but still get the same error. There is also *liblapack.so.3gf* and *libblas.so.3*, *libblas.so.3.0* and *libblas.a*, should I export any/either of those?

I've seen number of threads about this, but almost all of them include *apt-get*. I know that BLAS/LAPACK is installed on this machine, but I'm just not familiar enough with Linux to know exactly where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

One option to get a working *scipy* environment would be to install [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/why-anaconda).

Answer (score 0):

In general virtualenv does not work well with different versions of compiled extensions. If you want to have different versions of scipy & numpy installed simultaneously, the best tool is `conda`. See [this page](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html) for info on creating conda envs, which are like virtual envs but can handle non-python dependencies in a sane way.